# Top k results of a List Java

Tags: java, heapsort

I am using a Heap sort algorithm to sort an Object List and that is working fine. The problem is when I am trying to get the top k results of the list using this code:

```
HeapSort.sort(songs);
List<Song> highk = songs.subList(songs.size() - k, songs.size());
System.out.println(highk);
```

This prints the last k elements of the list. The k is fine because even if I change it with a number I have the same problem.

Comment: Why are you sorting `songs` in a loop?

Comment: Yes I just take it out of the loop and it returns the same

Comment: Do not sort list inside a loop, sort it outside.

Comment: This is not the problem. I updated the code and the problem is still happening.

Comment: Then what is your problem, could you please describe it? Is there an exception or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want top k elements, then your method call should be like below:

```
List<Song> highk = songs.subList(0, k);
```

When you see the java doc comments of the subList method, it clearly says, first argument is fromIndex and second argument is toIndex ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)).